# if vlook up value if not true make another match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Dear I need to look for value

```
 1    A               B             C
 2    date           day          desc    
 3    1/1/2015      Thursday      N/A    = I need if vlookup not find it in the below table
 4    1/2/2015     Friday         N/A      run another if like if(or( SAT,SUN),if true weekend
 5    1/2/2015     Sunday         Exam     if false keep as is (B2).
```

Defined schedule

```
date          day        desc
1/2/2015      Sunday     Exam
```

Comment: Which do you want to use for your code, Javascript, excel VBA or excel Formula?   Could you make the data example readable? I have difficulty to understand your problem.

Comment: i NEED TO USE EXCEL .... THE SITE NOT ALLOW ME TO UPLOAD THE PIC ... SO, WHAT i NEED if the vlookup dosent find the value in the table that he is going to get information from, instead of having NA I need to use another fomula like if saturday or sunday make it weekend otherwize keep the value in cell b ...... if you have an email I can send it to you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question right, so I try to restate it. You are doing a VLOOKUP, but you have cases where there is no match in the reference table. Therefore you get N/A as result. In such cases you would like to check whether the value in column B is Saturday or Sunday. If so, you will write weekend, otherwise you will repeat the value of column B.

With excel formulas I would solve your problem like this (I will simulate this in your D3 cell):

```
=IFERRORS(VLOOKUP(... <<put here your references following VLOOKUP formula instructions>>...), IF(OR(B3 = "Saturday", B3 = "Sunday"), "Weekend", B3)
```